# How does StampedLock queue lock requests?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I am investigating locking a cache based on Java8's **`StampedLock`** ([javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html)) but I can't find a convincing implementation on the net to follow, despite reading articles like [*StampedLock Idioms*](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue215.html).

I don't feel very positive about Java's multi-threading and concurrency offerings after being shocked that `ReentrantReadWriteLock` doesn't allow upgrading of a read lock to a write lock, followed by the difficulty homing in on a reputable alternative solution.

My issue is that there's no definitive statement to allay my fears that `StampedLock` will block write requests indefinitely while there are read requests queued.

Looking at the documentation, there are 2 comments which raise my suspicions.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html):

> The scheduling policy of StampedLock does not consistently prefer
>   readers over writers or vice versa. All "try" methods are best-effort
>   and do not necessarily conform to any scheduling or fairness policy.

From the [source code](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/StampedLock.java?view=co):

```
 * These rules apply to threads actually queued. All tryLock forms
 * opportunistically try to acquire locks regardless of preference
 * rules, and so may "barge" their way in.  Randomized spinning is
 * used in the acquire methods to reduce (increasingly expensive)
 * context switching while also ....
```

So it hints at a queue for read and write locks but I'd need to read and digest the whole 1500 lines of source code to nail it.

I assume it must be there because I found a [good benchmarking article](http://isuru-perera.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/benchmarking-java-locks-with-counters.html) which shows that `StampedLock` is the way to go for many reads / few writes. However I'm still concerned because of the lack of coverage online.

Fundamentally I guess I expected an implementation where I could plug'n'play following the javadoc, but in the end I'm left rooting around the net wondering why there isn't an example anywhere of a looped `StampedLock#tryOptimisticRead()` - even the [code from the benchmark article](https://github.com/chrishantha/microbenchmarks/blob/v0.0.1-initial-counter-impl/counters/src/main/java/com/github/chrishantha/microbenchmark/counter/impl/OptimisticStampedCounter.java) doesn't do that.

Is Java concurrency this difficult or have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score -1):

> "Is Java concurrency this difficult or have I missed something obvious?"

It is a matter of opinion<sup>1</sup> whether Java concurrency is more difficult than (say) C++ or Python concurrency.

But yes, concurrency is difficult<sup>2</sup> in any language that allows different threads to directly update shared data structures.  Languages that (only) support CSP-like concurrency are easier to understand and reason about.

Reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes

---

To your point about fairness, it is true that most forms of locking in Java do not guarantee *fairness*.  And indeed many things to do with thread scheduling are (deliberately) *loosely specified*.  But it is not difficult to write code that avoids these problems ... once you understand the libraries and how to use them.

---

To your specific issue about `StampedLock` behavior.

> My issue is that there's no definitive statement to allay my fears that `StampedLock` will block write requests indefinitely while there are read requests queued.

There is no such statement<sup>3</sup> because such behavior is possible.  It follows from a careful reading of the `StampedLock` API documentation.  For example, it says:

> *"The scheduling policy of `StampedLock` does not consistently prefer readers over writers or vice versa."*

In short, there is nothing there that guarantees that an untimed `writeLock` will eventually acquire the lock.

If you need to categorically avoid the scenario of readers causing writer starvation, then don't use `writeLock` and `readLock`.  You could use `tryOptimisticRead` instead of `readLock`.  Or you could design and implement a different synchronization mechanism.

---

Finally, you seems to be implying that `StampedLock` *should* provide a way to directly deal with your scenario and / or that the document should specifically explain  to non-expert users how to deal with it.  I draw people's attention to this:

> "*StampedLocks are designed for use as internal utilities in the development of thread-safe components.*".

The fact that you are having difficulty finding pertinent examples in not the fault of the javadocs.  If anything, it supports the inference that this API is for experts ...

---

<sup>1 - My opinion is that Java's concurrency support is at least easier to reason about than most other languages of its ilk.  The Java Memory Model (Chapter 17.4 of the JLS) is well specified, and "Java Concurrency In Practice" by Goetz et al does a good job of explaining the ins and outs of concurrent programming.

2 - .... for most programmers.

3 - If this is not definitive enough for you, write yourself an example where there is a (simulated) indefinitely large sequence of read requests and multiple reader threads.  Run it and see if the writer threads get stalled until the read requests are all drained.</sup>